# JS addEventListener not working consistently

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener

I am trying to build a simple to-do app.
I have created my list with a delete icons and I want to remove the item when corresponding delete icon is clicked.

my html

```
<ul class="list-group todos mx-auto text-light">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <span>Study test</span>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <span>Do the hw</span>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

my js

```
const list= document.querySelector('.todos');
list.addEventListener('click', e => {
   if(e.target.classList.contains('delete')){
       e.target.parentElement.remove();
   }
});
```

when I add couple of todo items and then press the delete icon, it is not removing the list item. Sometimes it is working on 2. click, sometimes nothing happens and rarely working as intended. It's behavior changes with every page refresh.

Comment: "Not working" is not a good problem statement.

Comment: It appears to work fine for both items, when I test the code you have currently shown. _“Sometimes it is working, sometimes not.”_ - that is not helpful in figuring this out; you need to give us a [mre] that actually illustrates the issue properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your JS:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('.todos');

const listArray =  Array.from(list)

listArray.forEach(item => {
   item.addEventListener('click', e => {
      if(e.target.classList.contains('delete')){
          e.target.parentElement.remove();
      }
   });

})
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your code but it does not remove the list item.